# different 'average' options in jaccard_score method in sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, correlation, similarity, recommendation-engine

I am working on my thesis topics which is related to comparing different similarity metrics results on Top N recommender system.

I am facing issue understanding the different 'average' options in jaccard_score method in sklearn.metrics

which are  [ 'micro', 'macro', 'samples', 'weighted']

I am not getting their background calculation. How it varies.

My rating matrix would be very sparse so i need to decide which 'average' would be better for my research.

PS - After searching a lot i am sharing this problem here, if someone has already explained it somewhere please share.

Regards
Santosh